# Can I change the Chart.js same line with two colors?

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart represent too units 2018 can i change the color of specific months data. data will be like below

```
data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Units",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [11,2,34,57,3,33,67,12,2,2,66,44]
    }],
  },
```

Comment: no such option given in documentation.

Comment: okay sir thanks, but if i get a the data as a example for `nov` and `dec` as another data set it shows with `jan` and `feb` how can i use that data set on `nov` and `dec`

Comment: make an array of data labels with your choice of values e.g `nov, dec` and pass it...